# angular4 bootstrap.css doesn't include

Tags: angular

I include bootstrap,but the stylesheet doesn't show in html

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/_bootstrap@3.3.7@bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

But in chrome injection,bootstrap.min.css didn't included obviously

```
<style type="text/css">/* You can add global styles to this file, and also 
import other style files */
</style>
<style></style>
```

Comment: have you restarted the server after changing the angular cli file?

Comment: Oh,that's why.Thank you very much

Comment: Great! I will you post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Always restart the server after changing the angular-cli file.